# Retrieve specific data from firebase real time database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> From database I want to show only bsc it 3 stream not all stream details.

UserHelperclass is model class.

This code display all users:

[image: Screenshot of a tree-like database structure]

```
usersList = new ArrayList<>();

final my_class_adapter class_adapter = new my_class_adapter(my_class.this, usersList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(class_adapter);

databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UsersData");

usersListener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        usersList.clear();

        for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            UserHelperClass userHelperClass = itemSnapshot.getValue(UserHelperClass.class);
            usersList.add(userHelperClass);
        }
        class_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean through "show only bsc it 3 stream not all stream details"?

Answer (score 0):

```
// define the object
UserHelperclass user_class;
ArrayList<UserHelperclass> dataList=new ArrayList()<>;

Query qry = databaseReference.getRoot().child("UsersData").orderByChild("stream").equalTo("Bsc It 3");

        qry.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSanpshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    // store data into your model class   
                   user_class=dataSanpshot1.getvalue(UserHelperclass.class);

                   // add model class data to the arraylist
                    dataList.add(user_class);
                 }
               // now set arraylist to your adapter of recyclerview pr gridview or listview

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(CodeActivity.this, "fail to get data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```